# How to print this matrix the way I want?

Tags: java, multiplication

I'm new to java so I was wondering how I can print my matrix like this  :

```
         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
         2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
         3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
         4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
         5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
         6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60
         7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70
         8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80
         9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90
        10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

This is my code :

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;



void program() {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         
        out.print("Give me the size of your wished multiplication table : ");

        int a = sc.nextInt();

        int[][] multiplication = new int[a][a];

        int base = 0;
        int number = 1;
        for (int head = 0 ; head < a ; head++) {
            base++;
            number = 1;
            for (int side = 0; side < a ; side++) {
                multiplication[head][side] =base* number;
                number++; 
            }

        }

        for (int[] s : multiplication) {
            out.println((Arrays.toString(s)).replace("[","").replace("]",""));
        }
}
```

The output is this if you give it 10 for example :

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20
3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30
4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50
6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60
7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70
8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80
9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90
10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100
```

which is not what I want, I want it to be in the same line. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You could skip putting the values to the array and instead directly write them to the output. And to make the values aligned, you probably want to convert them first to a String, like `println(addLeadingSpace(base * number));`.

Comment: You need to take control of formatting each number, see the answer below. Relying on `Arrays.toString` does not give you that control.

Answer (score 2):

(assuming `multiplication` is a 2D array of int):

```java
       for(var row : multiplication) {
            for(var col : row) {
                System.out.printf("%-3d", col);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```